# Android jobScheduler Projects

Tags: android

Seeking well-organized Android Kotlin projects or YouTube tutorials utilizing JobScheduler for background tasks. Any recommended GitHub repositories or tutorials appreciated. As i'm searching for quite a long time but cann't manage a fruitful one.